# Как в реализации шифра двойной перестановки сделать порядок столбцов и строк постоянным?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как в данном коде сделать так, чтобы количество и порядок столбцов и строк всегда был постоянным, или чтобы количество и порядок можно было задавать с клавиатуры? Например, есть всего 4 строки в порядке (3, 1, 4, 2) и 4 столбца в порядке (4, 1, 3, 2). И чтобы, если в таблице останутся пустые ячейки, то чтобы они тоже выводились (или вставить в них какой-то специальный символ, например, "-").
Я знаю python только на базовом уровне.
Про шифр двойной перестановки хорошо описано в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80#%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8).
Код программы:

```
from math import ceil
from random import shuffle
s = list('двойная перестановка')
s1 = round(len(s)**0.5)
s2 = ceil(len(s)**0.5)
a = [[s.pop(0) if s else ' ' for _ in range(s1)] for _ in range(s2)]
shuffle(a)
a = list(map(list,zip(*a)))
shuffle(a)
print(''.join([i for j in a for i in j]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
s = list('двойная перестановка'.replace(' ', ''))
col = [3, 1, 4, 2]
row = [3, 2, 4, 1, 5]

a = [ s[i*len(col):(i+1)*len(col)] for i in range(len(row)) ]

if len(a[-1]) < len(col):
    a[-1].extend(list(' '*(len(col)-len(a[-1]))))

for i in a:
    print(*i)

a = [[a[i][col.index(j+1)] for j in range(len(col))] for i in range(len(row))]

a = [a[row.index(i+1)] for i in range(len(row))]

print('-'*7)
for i in a:
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Всё понятно. Кое-какие моменты для себя посмотрю в интернете.

Comment: Проверил код. Он отлично работает, если строк на 1 меньше, чем столбцов. А вот есть строк и столбцов равное количество, или отличное от 1, то тогда перестановки получаются неверными...

Comment: а вы изменяли значения col и row при изменении текста? можете дать проверочные данные

Comment: s = list('АБРАМОВ+ДЯДИНА'.replace(' ', ''))
col = [4, 1, 3, 2]
row = [3, 1, 4, 2]

Comment: При таком примере строки встают правильно, а вот из столбцов только первый на своём месте

Comment: согласен. исправил часть где перемешивал столбцы, попробуйте!

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь! Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать ещё один момент? Как можно здесь в python вывести полученную таблицу в строку сверху вниз по столбцам? Чтобы получился такой результат: "ОАБЯ+ АИВ РДМНАД". Пробелы тоже выводятся. Это результат того преобразования, пример исходной строки которого был выше в комментариях.

Comment: Сделал так, но вывод получится построчно: print(''.join([i for j in a for i in j]))

Comment: @EgaNator не придумал ничего лучше чем пересобрать массив. получилось так: for i in [[a[j][i] for j in range(len(col))] for i in range(len(row))]: print(''.join(i), end='') #ОАБЯ+ АИВ РДМНАД

Comment: Большое спасибо!